# Internal EndPoint Call with Parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get an array in an ednpoint, this endpoint must call another endpoint by passing a "sum" variable and the index value "i" in a for loop until all the array values ​​have been passed, the internal end point When you receive the variable "sum" and the value of the index "i", you must do the sum and return this value to the endpoint that called it.

My question is how to call this second endpoint by passing the variable and index value and getting its return.

Router numbers

```
 app.get('/numbers/sum', (req,res) => {    
     var array = req.body.num;  
     var sum = 0 
     for (i in array){
         sum = fetch('localhost:3000/number/sum/${sum,i}') //example
     }
 })
```

Router number

```
app.get('/number/sum/', (req,res) => {    
    var sum,value_index = req.body
    Number.sum(sum,value_index)
    return soma // returns the sum for the endpoint that called it

})
```

Comment: Cool. What's the question?

Comment: how to make an internal endpoint call by passing the parameters described in the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the way you have depicted the code might endup you getting some wrong value as api call is an asynchronous call and we can directly capture the value , the way you have written. I would recommend you to follow this approach . I have used async await methodology to deal with async behaviour other wise promise is also and idea candidate . I believe you are using fetch npm module to invoke endpoint.

```js
app.get('/numbers/sum', async (req,res) => {    
     const numbers = req.body.num;  
     let sum = 0; 
     for (let i in numbers){
         sum = await fetch(`localhost:3000/number/sum/${sum}/${i}`)
     }
     return res.status(200).json({success: true, sum: sum })
 })
```

Comment: I still have questions about the return of the sum variable, as it returns in the end point "app.get ('/ number / sum /: sum /: value_index', (req, res)" and how to get this return in the endpoint "app .get ('/ numbers / sum', async (req, res) "?

Comment: You can get those properties from req like below 
sum = req.params.sum;
num = req.params.num;

result = sum+num;

then do the sum operation and send response 
res.status(200).json({success: true, sum: result })